# How to get my web text below my logo and navbar?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a simple web page. It has a logo in the upper left corner, and on the same line to the right is a navbar. That all works fine. The problem is that I want to then have text below the logo & navbar (full width). No matter what I try, the text starts in the same line as the logo and navbar. How can I force the text to start below the logo & navbar?

Here's the html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Temp.css" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="logo" style="display:inline;">
            <a href="Temp.html">
                <img src="robert-half-technology-logo-600(40).gif"/>
            </a>
        </div>

        <nav class="navbar  navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#" style="color:black;">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Temp_AboutUs.html" style="color:black;">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Temp_Careers.html" style="color:black;">Careers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Temp_ContactUs.html" style="color:black;">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><br/><br/>
        </nav>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <h1>About Us</h1>
                    <p class="normaltext">
                        Founded in 1948, Robert Half has a long company history of innovation, always guided by high ethical standards and the belief that finding the right fit for a client and candidate creates an engaged and energized workforce.
                    </p>
                    <p class="normaltext">
                        We pioneered the idea of professional staffing services nearly 70 years ago and, as the needs of businesses have evolved, so have we. In 1986, when current leadership acquired the Robert Half business from founder Bob Half, the staffing industry was much different than it is today. Our leadership team saw potential in moving toward a more specialized staffing approach and began placing temporary workers at higher skill levels. Our clients and candidates found value in professional-level staffing, which is why we launched a series of temporary professional staffing divisions in the finance and accounting, legal, creative and marketing, technology and administrative fields. And in 2002, we again saw opportunity and introduced Protiviti, a global independent risk consulting and internal audit service, to support companies as they faced more stringent financial reporting and disclosure practices under new regulations such as Sarbanes-Oxley.
                    </p>
                    <p class="normaltext">
                        Explore Robert Half’s history, learn about our leadership and accolades and see how we have found opportunity in innovation to create a $5 billion professional services organization.
                    </p>
                    <h2>1940s: The beginning</h2>
                    <table style="width:100%" class="normaltext">
                        <tr>
                            <td>1948</td>
                            <td>Robert Half founded by Bob and Maxine Half.</td> 
                        </tr>
                    </table>  
                    <h2>1960s: High ethical standards become a cornerstone</h2>
                    <table style="width:100%" class="normaltext">
                        <tr>
                            <td>1963</td>
                            <td style="padding-left:20px;">Bob Half speaks out against discriminatory recruiting and staffing practices in a letter to the Association of Personnel Agencies of New York.</td> 
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <h2>1970s: A decade of firsts</h2>
                    <table style="width:100%" class="normaltext">
                        <tr>
                            <td>1973</td>
                            <td style="padding-left:20px">Robert Half opens its first international location in London.</td> 
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>1973</td>
                            <td style="padding-left:20px;">Accountemps, the first of many professional staffing divisions, is launched, thus beginning Robert Half’s specialized approach to temporary staffing.</td> 
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

And here's the css:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: #dddddd;
}

.logo {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2000;
}

.video {
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
z-index: -100;
-ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
-moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
transform: translateX (-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

h1 {
    text-align:center;
    color:#a01b35;
}

.normaltext {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: "Futura BT W01 Book",OpenSansRegular,"Open Sans Regular",sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.25;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give margin-top to the container as much as need to accomodate Header height and give top:0px css to .logo class.

```
.container {
    width: 1170px;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.logo{
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 2000;
   top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's is because you are using a fixed navbar and logo so it sits on top of your container below.

Just apply a margin-top to your .container class and top:0 to your .logo class:

```
.container {
    margin-top: 50px; //use what ever you need here for spacing.
}

.logo {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2000;
}
```

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: #dddddd;
}

.logo {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2000;
}

.video {
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
z-index: -100;
-ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
-moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
transform: translateX (-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

h1 {
    text-align:center;
    color:#a01b35;
}

.normaltext {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: "Futura BT W01 Book",OpenSansRegular,"Open Sans Regular",sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.25;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Temp.css" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="logo" style="display:inline;">
            <a href="Temp.html">
                <img src="robert-half-technology-logo-600(40).gif"/>
            </a>
        </div>

        <nav class="navbar  navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#" style="color:black;">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Temp_AboutUs.html" style="color:black;">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Temp_Careers.html" style="color:black;">Careers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Temp_ContactUs.html" style="color:black;">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><br/><br/>
        </nav>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <h1>About Us</h1>
                    <p class="normaltext">
                        Founded in 1948, Robert Half has a long company history of innovation, always guided by high ethical standards and the belief that finding the right fit for a client and candidate creates an engaged and energized workforce.
                    </p>
                    <p class="normaltext">
                        We pioneered the idea of professional staffing services nearly 70 years ago and, as the needs of businesses have evolved, so have we. In 1986, when current leadership acquired the Robert Half business from founder Bob Half, the staffing industry was much different than it is today. Our leadership team saw potential in moving toward a more specialized staffing approach and began placing temporary workers at higher skill levels. Our clients and candidates found value in professional-level staffing, which is why we launched a series of temporary professional staffing divisions in the finance and accounting, legal, creative and marketing, technology and administrative fields. And in 2002, we again saw opportunity and introduced Protiviti, a global independent risk consulting and internal audit service, to support companies as they faced more stringent financial reporting and disclosure practices under new regulations such as Sarbanes-Oxley.
                    </p>
                    <p class="normaltext">
                        Explore Robert Half’s history, learn about our leadership and accolades and see how we have found opportunity in innovation to create a $5 billion professional services organization.
                    </p>
                    <h2>1940s: The beginning</h2>
                    <table style="width:100%" class="normaltext">
                        <tr>
                            <td>1948</td>
                            <td>Robert Half founded by Bob and Maxine Half.</td> 
                        </tr>
                    </table>  
                    <h2>1960s: High ethical standards become a cornerstone</h2>
                    <table style="width:100%" class="normaltext">
                        <tr>
                            <td>1963</td>
                            <td style="padding-left:20px;">Bob Half speaks out against discriminatory recruiting and staffing practices in a letter to the Association of Personnel Agencies of New York.</td> 
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <h2>1970s: A decade of firsts</h2>
                    <table style="width:100%" class="normaltext">
                        <tr>
                            <td>1973</td>
                            <td style="padding-left:20px">Robert Half opens its first international location in London.</td> 
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>1973</td>
                            <td style="padding-left:20px;">Accountemps, the first of many professional staffing divisions, is launched, thus beginning Robert Half’s specialized approach to temporary staffing.</td> 
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: unfortunately, that lowers the logo 50px too. i need to keep the logo and the navbar at the top, and just have the text lowered.

Comment: You need to add top: 0 to your logo class too.